# The meaning of tensors in the neural network community

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, tensor

In the neural network community, is a tensor pretty much always just a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: At least for Theano and TensorFlow this seems to be the case.

Comment: Yes, in the same sense that a matrix is just a 2 dimensional array.  But tensors just simplify notation and programming just as matrix operation simplifies multivariate methods. In particular for a convolutional net,  you have 1 image (tile)  being processed by a bank of filters,  which can be expressed as a single tensor operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensors in the neural network community = vector (1D-tensor), matrix/array  (2D-tensor), or multi-dimensional array  (nD-tensor, with $n > 2$).

Examples:

[image]

[image]

---

Related: [Why the sudden fascination with tensors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198061/why-the-sudden-fascination-with-tensors)